# Ebean overridden save, update methods are not getting called through cascade save, update

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

I have a base class:

```
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;
import javax.persistence.PrePersist;
import javax.persistence.PreUpdate;
import javax.persistence.Version;

import play.db.ebean.Model;

@MappedSuperclass
public class TimeStampable extends Model {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long id;

    @Column(name = "created_at")
    public Date createdAt;

    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    public Date updatedAt;

    @Version
    public int version;

    @Override
    public void save() {
        if (this.id == null) {
            createdAt();
        } else {
            updatedAt();
        }
        super.save();
    }

    @Override
    public void update() {
        updatedAt();
        super.update();
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Object o) {
        updatedAt();
        super.update(o);
    }

    @PrePersist
    void createdAt() {
        this.createdAt = this.updatedAt = new Date();
    }

    @PreUpdate
    void updatedAt() {
        this.updatedAt = new Date();
    }
}
```

And 2 models

```
public class Request extents TimeStampable {
     @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
     public List<Response> responses = new ArrayList<Response>();
}

public class Response extents TimeStampable {
}
```

when I try to save a Request object, I see that my DB has created_at updated_at fields correctly populated for the Request object but for the Response objects, those values are null. Other fields of the response objects have the expected values (that I had filled in).

Here is how I am saving the request.

```
Request req = new Request();
Response res = new Response();
// code to populate response fields

request.add(res);
Ebean.save(req);
```

What am i missing here?

Comment: Can you show the code for the controller/logic to save `Request` and `Response` object?

Comment: I added the code that I am using to save request object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the `@PrePersist` or `@PreUpdate` doesn't called with the logic you provided. These operation executed when invoke manually using `save()` method. I have found two solution for your problem.

First, Because you use **unidirectional** `OneToMany` relation (the `Response` object may not know the `Request` object associated with it because there is no field with type `Request` on `Response` object), it will not allow to invoke `save()` method on `Response` object before the `Request` object is saved.

If you insist to use this relation type. On `TimeStampable` model add these annotation on the `createdAt` and `updatedAt` field :

```java
@Column(name = "created_at")
@CreatedTimestamp
public Date createdAt;

@Column(name = "updated_at")
@UpdatedTimestamp
public Date updatedAt;
```

These two annotation are eBean annotation.

Second alternative is, you may use **bidirectional** relationship between `Response` and `Request` class. On `Response` class add the field to reference `Request` object.

```java
public class Response extends Timestampable {
    @ManyToOne // to make relation bidirectional
    public Request request;
}
```

on `TimeStamp` superclass you can **remove** `@UpdatedTimestamp` or `@CreatedTimestamp` annotation, because you can invoke `save()` method here on controller. Here is example to populate data on controller if you use this approach:

```java
// create new request object and save
Request request = new Request();
request.save();

// populate the response
Response response1 = new Response();
response.request = request;
Response response2 = new Response();
response.request = request;
response.save();
response.save();
```

---

> #### Suggestion
>
> I suggest you to use the second approach, because if you had `Response` object you will know the `Request` object that associated with it.